# Flutter and google places API results

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

hope someone can help me with this.

I've managed to return search autocomplete results and for the most part everything is ok and results are almost restricted to the area but ocassionaly I get areas outside of the radius when non of the queried letters match the area.

However I want to apply restrictions to display results that are only in the specified area/radius. I've tried applying strictbounds parameter, but strictbounds combined with types : 'address' is just showing no results or single result. When I remove types the results automatically show only points of interest which I don't need. Only need addresses.

Anyone have any idea whats wrong in this?

```
Uri uri = Uri.https("maps.googleapis.com", "maps/api/place/autocomplete/json", {
  "input": query,
  "location": poznanLocation,
  "language": "pl",
  "radius": searchRadius,
  "key": apiKey,
  "bounds": "52.22,15.33|53.13,17.36",
  "strictbounds": "true",
  "types": "address",
  "sessiontoken": _sessionToken,
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the [appropriate docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete). The Places Autocomplete web service does not have a `bounds` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there *are* suitable results that should be returned?

Depending on the values of `location` and `radius`(*), there may be *no* suitable results left after adding *both* `strictbounds` and `types=address`.

If results are returned when removing `strictbounds`, are they *strictly* within the region defined by `location` and `radius`? If they are, please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=787713). Otherwise, that is *precisely* the intended behavior of `strictbounds`.

(*) The Place Autocomplete web service will ignore the `bounds` parameter, because it is not supported.